# Rails 3 finding parents which have no child

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a one to many relationship with no counter cache how can I find parents with no child?

user.rb

```
has_many :pages
```

page.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I've tried

```
User.includes(:pages).where("pages.user_id is NULL")
```

This is making trouble in MySQL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
User.joins("left join pages on pages.user_id = users.id").where("pages.user_id is null")
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot as well !

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
User.where("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages WHERE pages.user_id = users.id) = 0")
```

But I'm not sure how (in)efficient that would be.

Comment: count(*) is not something that i'd personally want to run if it was a common query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like

```
 User.all(:joins => :comments, :select => "users.*, count(comments.id) as comments_count", :group => "users.id")
```

might work also...