# ActiveRecord: inverse of includes (find all with no nested object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3 finding parents which have no child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565879/rails-3-finding-parents-which-have-no-child)

I need to find all objects that does not have a nested object attached.

I'm aware of `User.all.includes(:address)` includes all with an "address" nested object but I'm not sure how to do the opposite.

The schema looks something like this. There's no `User.address_id` attribute.

```
User
has_one :address

Address
belongs_to :user
user_id: integer
address: string
```

Comment: Why its needed? I expect only to check for `User.address` nested object presence.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I made a stupid mistake in the previous answer.

Here is a proper solution. You could do a query to find the Users with addresses then you can filter the Users without the address by passing the result of the previous query to another query.

Do this:

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT users.id FROM users INNER JOIN addresses ON users.id=addresses.user_id)");
```

Btw this is a good question. Wonder why it was down voted.