# How to convert this query to ActiveRecord logic?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working in rails. My model is like this:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics, dependent: :delete_all
  belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'topic_id', class_name: 'Topic'
  has_many :contents

  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

So I have a topic that can have many "sub-topics". **Every sub-topic can have many sub-topics, indefinitely**. I'm trying to make a method that returns me all "leaf" topics. A leaf topic is a topic with no sub-topics.

```
def self.leafs
  where(???)
end
```

I can't formulate this in active record logic, so actually I use this query:

```
Topic.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT t.topic_id FROM topics t WHERE topic_id IS NOT NULL)")
```

How can I write this in an active record way?

Comment: you can refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082096/rails-4-scope-to-find-parents-with-no-children

Comment: @Sontya I tryed, but `Topic.includes(:topics).where(topics: { id: nil })` returns always an empty set.

Comment: @Sontya `Topic.includes(:topics).where(topics: { id: nil }).to_sql` -> "SELECT \"topics\".* FROM \"topics\"  WHERE \"topics\".\"id\" IS NULL", that is wrong.

Comment: TRy this `Topic.joins(:topics).where(topics: {id: nil})`

Comment: @Sontya empty set... to_sql returns: `SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "topics" "topics_topics" ON "topics_topics"."topic_id" = "topics"."id" WHERE "topics_topics"."topic_id" IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
child_ids_with_topic_id = where.not(topic_id: nil).pluck(:topic_id)
where.not(id: child_ids_with_topic_id)
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear... Every sub-topic can have many sub-topics, indefinitely. So a topic with `topic_id != null` is not a leaf, is just a non-parent. I want all topics with no children, not all topics that have a parent.

Comment: See if it finds your expected outputs, we can refactor it later.

Comment: Ok! This obtains the expected results! It's a bit raw, because it uses 2 queries... but I think that it can be improved :)

Comment: Okay, now I can improve it. I was not getting your question in the first place. :)

Comment: No problem, probably it was a bit unclear ;) I finally obtained this: `where.not(id: where('topic_id IS NOT NULL').select(:topic_id))`

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.leafs
  topics.where("topic_id IS NOT NULL")
end
```

ActiveRecord 4.0 and above adds where.not so you can do this:

```
scope :leafs, -> topics.where.not(topic_id: nil)


scope :without_topics, includes(:topics).where(:topics => { :id => nil })
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the request. This will search for all non-root topics, not for leafs...

Comment: try this: topics.where.not(topic_id: nil)

Comment: `scope :without_topics, includes(:topics).where(:topics => { :id => nil })` returns always an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Although i am not sure but i have tried using this [Rails 3 finding parents which have no child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565879/rails-3-finding-parents-which-have-no-child/6565939#6565939)

```
scope :leafs, joins("left join topics as sub_topics sub_topics.topic_id = topics.id").where("topics.topic_id is null")
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`